# How do i upgrade my pre-populated sqlite database on my device without re-creating tables?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have my code below. It correctly reads my sqlite database file(that i have already created using the SQLite Database Browser) in my assets folder - moves it to the /data/data/packagename/databases/ path on my device then i am able to use a query and cursor to get my information and it works great. Code here:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private Context myDbContext;
private static String dbName = "restaurant.db";
private static String outfilePath = "/data/data/dev.mypackage.com/databases/";
private static String path = outfilePath + dbName;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, dbName, null, 2);
    this.myDbContext = context;
    db = openDb();
    String s = "select * from menu";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(s, null);
    Log.e("DB Constructor Row count", String.valueOf(c.getCount()).toString());

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        Log.e("DB Constructor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category")));
        Log.e("DB Constructor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("menuItem_id")));
        Log.e("DB Constructor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
        Log.e("DB Constructor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("desc")));
        Log.e("DB Constructor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("price")));
        Log.e("DB Constructor", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("icon")));
    }

    c.deactivate();
    c.close();
}

private void copyDataBase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
    try{
        InputStream dbStream = myDbContext.getAssets().open(dbName);
        OutputStream newDbFile = new FileOutputStream(outfilePath + dbName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = dbStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            newDbFile.write(buffer);
        }

        newDbFile.flush();
        newDbFile.close();
        dbStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){

        throw new IOException("trying to copy the database - ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }   

}

private SQLiteDatabase openDb() throws SQLiteException{
    File dbFile = myDbContext.getDatabasePath(dbName);

    if(!dbFile.exists()){
        Log.e("openDb", "file does not exist");

        try {
            copyDataBase(dbFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
        }
    }

    return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}
public void loadRestaurantInfo(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

Now i had to go back and add a row of information to one of the tables(in the database in the assets folder), using the SQLite Brower, - but that is not being reflected in my cursor output - I understand why this is happening - because if(!dbFile.exists()) fails so there is no copying to be done. So my question is - is what code do i need to add to make this work? I never created the tables with code so i dont see how useful the onUpgrade method is going to be for me.

Comment: Do not hardwire paths. Use `getDatabasePath()` to create a path to a database file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Use onUpgrade() (preferred)
2. Delete the existing database and copy the new one (not a good idea)
3. Copy the data in the existing database, delete the existing database, copy the new database, insert data from old database into new database (too much work when the new database schema can be upgraded in onUpgrade).

So, to answer your question, you upgrade your database in onUpgrade() without having to recreate any tables.

On the other hand, if you just added a new row to a particular table, the database schema has not changed and you can just insert the new row at runtime... of course, not knowing what your application's purpose is this may not be a good idea as you can easily lose track of changes to your "static" database.

Comment: OK if i choose to do #1 - onUpgrade then i guess thats what i am wondering about. since i am not going to be writing queries(inserts, alter tables etc) in this method like most people have done - then what exactly do I do?

Comment: You can do anything onUpgrade(). The idea is to manage the user version of the database. I suggest you use onUpgrade() to run a simple sql query that will insert the new row in the corresponding table. If you give me the row data and table name I can show you an example, it's really easy. PS I'll need the table's columns' names as well.

Comment: I understand but what i was trying to get away from was having a bunch of hardcoded sql queries. For instance what if i needed to add 100 new rows? That would make my head hurt. What if i had to come back the next time and remove 25 of them because i decided i didn't need those specific ones? then i wold have to hunt down those 25 looking through all those insert statements. I was thinking that i would just need to make a new database file or somehow delete the database that was created(from copying from assets) - not sure how this would work -

Comment: Well, if your database is truly "static" then I think option # 2 is the right answer for you. By "static" I mean that no end user makes any changes to the data in the database. If that is the case all you need to do is get rid of the "if" statement in the openDb() method so that your database in your assets folder will always be copied.

Comment: basically i would like to just either use the SQLIte Browser or change my database via the terminal and copy the updated db in my assets folder and copy those changes onto external memory without having to write/change my onUpgrade method everytime i have a change.

Comment: yeah right now any end user cannot change the database - but what if someday i wanted to give them that ability? I dont think they should go swimming through code to make changes in the onUpgrade method. It would much easier for them to write an alter, drop, insert statement in a terminal or use the SQLite browser and copy those changes into the already existing db file in the assets folder. If i want to just delete the database in my assets folder and start again what about the copy that is on the device? Is it sitting in memory somewhere or is it deleted when the apk file is rebuilt?

Comment: I updated my previous comment. If you just want to copy the new database, then place the new database into your assets folder and then comment out the if(!dbFile.exists()) line in your openDb() method so that the database will always be copied.

Comment: If you want endusers to have the ability to modify the database at runtime then option # 2 is not a good idea. If the database will never be modified at runtime then option # 2 is what you are looking for (see previous comments for implementation).

Comment: The database in the device will remain there unless the application is uninstalled or you explicitly delete it.

Comment: ok - i actually did try this before and i kept getting an error from the copy method. my string for my FileOutputStream should have been outfilePath + dbName not dbFile. So thats my fault but i think this thread was still useful - thanks for the help - everything works fine. :)(i just removed the check) Accepted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8763/discussion-between-whatzit-toya-and-cspam)

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to do things is quite different from how you've set out. Rather than go there, I'll assume you want to keep your current method of creating your database and I'll offer a suggestion to work with it. Add a table to your database which has a single row of meta data, which will include the database version (as well as anything else you like). If the database file already exists, open it and check the version. If the version is old, close it and replace it.