# Android SQLite code doesn't work after switching from Mac OSX to windows 7

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

Last night i had  [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658824/how-do-i-upgrade-my-pre-populated-sqlite-database-on-my-device-without-re-creati)  working at home and Whatzit was a good help. I got everything working(commented out the dbFile exists check and just copied any changes to the database that i wanted to make using the sqlite browser).

This morning i bring in my tablet to a windows 7 machine, uninstalled the application and tried to run the same code from eclipse. I keep getting an error:

> 03-12 11:51:39.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20365): Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: trying to copy the database - ERROR:
>   /data/data/mypackage/databases/restaurant.db: open failed:
>   ENOTDIR (Not a directory)

i had zipped up my project on my mac and unzipped it to the same project directory in eclipse on the windows machine and in eclipse just performed a refresh.

Would like any input on what i might try? I tried uninstalling the app, copying the .apk back over and installing it again but nothing seems to work. thanks.

*I am actually running this on an actual device - Motorola Xoom 4.0.3

```
    private void copyDataBase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
    try{
        InputStream dbStream = myDbContext.getAssets().open(dbName);
        Log.e("In copyDataBase", "Environment Directory: " + Environment.getDataDirectory().canRead());
        Log.e("In copyDataBase", "Environment Directory: " + Environment.getDataDirectory().canWrite());
        Log.e("In copyDataBase", "Environment Directory: " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        Log.e("In copyDataBase", "opened up file " + dbName + " successfully. - trying " + path.toString());
        OutputStream newDbFile = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + dbName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = dbStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
            newDbFile.write(buffer);
        }

        newDbFile.flush();
        newDbFile.close();
        dbStream.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){

        throw new IOException("trying to copy the database - ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }   

}
```

the results of canWrite and canRead both come back as false. As sure as i am typing here this was working flawlessly. I dont know why hooking up the tablet to a windows machine running the same version as eclipse would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is saying that the directory specified doesn't exist. You're clearly running this on a new virtual device correct? Is the version of android the same as what you initially developed on?

Comment: no this is on an actual tablet - Motorola Xoom Android 4.0.3.

Comment: i added some code at the top. - for some reason cannot read or write. i wish i was at home now so i could compare.

Comment: ok well i solved it. I have learned my lesson that you need to use Context.getFilesDir for the data path instead of hardcoding it. I am not sure why /data/data/packagename/databases was working last night. i dont think that has anything to do with working on a mac vs windows. Very mysterious.