# Upgrade pre-populated sqlite database tables without removing tables with user input?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating an Android app with a Sqlite DB that has a couple of tables with pre-populated data (500+ rows) and also has tables which will be user populated.

The way I plan on distributing the database is via the following method for adding a pre-populated database to an app [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

I have an issue with this however as when it comes to upgrades I will likely either be adding a number of rows to the pre-populated tables and possibly even modifying a lot of the data in the existing rows, I want to completely replace those existing tables with the tables from the new pre-populated tables, yet leave the user populated tables intact.

I found another post [How do i upgrade my pre-populated sqlite database on my device without re-creating tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658894/1172181) where a user suggests this may be the wrong approach entirely ("The "right" way to do things is quite different from how you've set out") as I want upgrades to be as efficient as possible. As I haven't actually published my first version yet should I be changing my approach?

What is the most effective approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The way I plan on distributing the database is via the following method for adding a pre-populated database to an app Using your own SQLite database in Android applications.

That code has been out of date for some time. Please consider using something more modern and supported, [like `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

> I want to completely replace those existing tables with the tables from the new pre-populated tables, yet leave the user populated tables intact

`SQLiteAssetHelper` supports two patterns out of the box:

- Replace the entire database with the new packaged copy
- Run your own SQL scripts to update the existing installed database, ignoring the copy packaged with your app

Since `SQLiteAssetHelper` is open source, you can see how Jeff Gilfelt wrote it and try to leverage that for somehow supporting your hybrid scenario.

Personally, unless you need to do joins between "pre-populated tables" and "user populated tables", I would encourage you to use two separate databases. One would be all of the pre-populated data, which you could replace completely as needed based on app updates. The other would hold the user tables, which you would handle with a more conventional `SQLiteOpenHelper`. And, you might be able to do joins even with two separate databases, using `ATTACH DATABASE`, though I have not personally tried that scenario.